# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in localhost after GC update to 87.0.4280.66

Tags: google-chrome, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

I work with Visual Studio 2017 and develop asp.net core (2.2) app’s.
I have set IIS-Express as dev webserver and Google Chrome as default browser.
In the project settings, I have set http://localhost:14300 as dev-url.

Since the last chrome update **Version 87.0.4280.66 (at 19.11.2020)** the app is compiled, the chrome browser is started, but the url seems to be changed “on the fly” from http://localhost:14300 (as defined) to http**s**:localhost (without port).
Therefore, an error message is showed in the browser:
**ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

The app is loaded - if I paste the url (http://localhost:14300) in another Browser or a new chrome tab, the app is loaded.
So.. I assume a bug in the latest Chrome update or a compatibility issue VS2017 <-> ISS Express <-> GC

I already have searched the Internet and found nothing yet (further, I already sent as issue to Google) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems as I have found the issue (I see no context, but this **has** solved my problem):
Note: Here **( 1 )** was https://localhost showed (instead of http://localhost:14300 as on the screenshot below).

[image: Screenshot1]

After launch with debug to IIS press the (i) **( 1 )** symbol

[image: Screenshot2]

Then select "Website-Einstellungen" **( 2 )**  (website settings)

[image: Screenshot3]
Then, I had to delete **( 3 )** all data to the website (localhost)

After doing that, the debug url (http://localhost:14300) was loaded correct again.

So... (for me) it seems as the update to Chrome Version 87.0.4280.66 had a problem regarding the already stored data and then (for whatever reason) has redirected
http://localhost:14300
to
http**s**:/localhost

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you may set the `launchSettings.json`'s IIS Express's launch Url to `"https://localhost"`.

I suggest you could check it to make sure the launch Url is right.

More details about the launchSettings.json, you could refer to below codes:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5761",
      "sslPort": 44365
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "AngularCore31": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I don't use (and don't want to use) https for localhost un the dev environment. In my launchSettings.json is configured http://localhost:14300 what is the correct setting (overtook from my project settings). But it seems as I have found the reason -> see my own answer.